# Click Div make another Div Appear

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a prompt box of sorts in which you click one div and another transitions from visibility = hidden to visibility = visible. This is my code so far and I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="C.K.">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
        <script type="text/js">
            document.getElementById("addpanel").onclick = document.getElementById("selector").style.visibility = "visble";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="selector">
            SELECTOR
        </div>
        <div id="addpanel">
            <table id="add">
                <tr>
                    <td id="plus">+</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Add New Item</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're attaching a handler to an element that doesn't exist when the JS runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="C.K.">
        <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="selector">
        SELECTOR
    </div>
    <div id="addpanel">
        <table id="add">
            <tr>
                <td id="plus">+</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Add New Item</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("selector").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("addpanel").onclick = function(){document.getElementById("selector").style.visibility = "visible";};
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked great! Might I ask the rationale behind such a method?

Comment: 1st - scripts always after the HTML, so the elements can be found.
2nd - you set up the onclick property as a javascript function, so it would actually execute the statement.

I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is parsed top to bottom.  Your script will be run immediately just in case it produces any more HTML for the parser to handle (e.g. with `document.write`).  At the point of `document.getElementById("addpanel").onclick`, `addpanel` does not exist because the HTML parser hasn't reached it yet.

Move your `<script>` block to after your `apppanel` element's closing tag.

Also, onclick needs to be a function.  So it would be:

```
document.getElementById("addpanel").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("selector").style.visibility = "visible"
}
```

Quick working example: https://jsfiddle.net/m2q6ubuv/

Comment: @ewwink haha I just copied it from the question, thanks!

Comment: @cobo16 Sorry, try with `visible` too

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> function show(){
>   document.getElmenetById('selector').style.visibility = 'visible'; }

Then just put `onclick='show()'` as an attribute in the tag you want to be the button.
Plus, you should put JavaScript at the end of the page, just first of the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Remember: this will let you show the div, but then the button won't more hide the div, for do that you have to use a more complex if/else JavaScript function